# "aws:Referer" in AWS Policy Generator is not visible or hase been deprected

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am tyring to replicate the code below because it is not working using the AWS Policy Generator:

```
{
"Version":"2008-10-17",
"Id":"http referer policy example",
"Statement":[
{
"Sid":"Allow get requests referred by www.cloudberrylab.com, cloudberrylab.com and IP address",
"Effect":"Allow",
"Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
"Action":"s3:GetObject",
"Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-wonderful-bucket.com/*",
"Condition":{
"StringLike":{
"aws:Referer":[
"http://www.cloudberrylab.com/*",
"http://cloudberrylab.com/*", "http://74.208.197.105/*"
]
}
}
}
]
}
```

In the conditon StringLike - aws:Referer does not exist. What can I use instead? The above code is used not to allow hotlinking but it is telling me - Policy has invalid resource - arn:aws:s3:::my-wonderful-bucket.com/

That is why i think it is from the fact that StringLike - aws:Referer does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Policy Generator does not equal to the spec.

See "Available Keys" section in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition